# How disable notifications in Centreon through Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, datacenter, centreon

I would like to disable some services notifications in Centreon through Nagios web interface.
Does anybody know how do that in Nagios ?

Comment: When asking questions like this it is useful to include: Nagios verstion, NDOUtils version and Centreon version. Please can you update your question to include this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming you mean disabling notifications from the Service Information page for a service, i.e. the one that contains the Service State Information table with the Service Command table on the right?:

[image]

If you click on "Disable notifications for this service" and confirm the "Commit" on the following page:

[image]

...Centreon will pick this up. You need to be patient because the command is queued and may not execute immediately. On a busy Nagios server it may take several minutes for the command to execute and for Centreon to see this change. When it does eventually happen you'll see a small "splat" next to the service under *Monitoring -> Services ->* :

[image]

This was verified on my test environment running Nagios 3.5.0, NDOUtils 1.4b9 and Centreon 2.4.4.

You can also verify when the command was sent by tailing the Nagios log:

```
tail -f /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log
```

When the command is processed you'll see something like:

```
[1378315436] EXTERNAL COMMAND: DISABLE_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS;Buzz;HTTP
```

Where `Buzz` is my host name and `HTTP` is the check name.

Your log location may vary and you can find it by checking the "Log file" configuration value in Centreon under:

```
Configuration -> Monitoring Engines -> main.cfg
```

Or, if you're running an older version prior to the release of the Centreon fork of Nagios:

```
Configuration -> Nagios -> nagios.cfg
```

[image]

If this isn't happening then we'd need to see your service configuration and "Data Processing" options.